# In XML does prefix equal namespace or belongs to namespace?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces, prefix

In the example is *foo* equal to "abc123" (that is just a shorthand) or belongs to "abc123" namespace?

```
<root xmlns:foo="abc123">
  <foo:parent>
    ...
  </foo:parent>
</root>
```

If it belongs, than it is possible to have many prefixes bound to the same namespace, like:

```
<root xmlns:a="namespace_A" xmlns:b="namespace_A">
   <a:element> ... </element>
   <b:element>     </element>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***[namespace prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-Prefix)*** (`foo`) serves as a placeholder for a ***[namespace name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-NSName)*** (`abc123`).  So, your *shorthand* label fits better.

Different namespace prefixes *may* be defined for the same namespace name, but different namespace names *may not* have the same namespace prefix.